# How to create a generic interface for a CRUD model?

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a generic interface in go for models I wish to use in my api.

```
type Model interface {
    Create(interface{}) (int64, error)
    Update(string, interface{}) (error)
}
```

And I have a personModel which implements it:

```
type Person struct {
    Id int `json:"id"`
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
}

type PersonModel struct {
    Db *sql.DB
}

func (model *PersonModel) Create(personStruct person) (int64, error) {
    // do database related stuff to create the person from the struct
}

func (model *PersonModel) Update(id string, personStruct person) (error) {
    // do database related stuff to update the person model from the struct
}
```

However, I can't get this to work, as I'm getting errors related to how the `PersonModel` does not implement the `Model` interface.

My main goal is to have a unified interface for all models in my application (implementing `create` and `update`) that can be used by the controllers. How would I go about overcoming this problem?

Comment: methods Create and Update need an empty interface{} as parameters no a person struct

Answer (score 1):

You should try to implement your method like this, it's just because you ask in your func Create and Update an empty interface as params :

```
func (model *PersonModel) Create(v interface{}) (int64, error) {
    // do database related stuff to create the person from the struct
}

func (model *PersonModel) Update(id string, v interface{}) (error) {
    // do database related stuff to update the person model from the struct
}
```